# Django ModelForm Submit To Database

Tags: python, django, view, django-forms

When I load my view at : localhost:8000/Scan, it throws an issue of:

```
TypeError on views.py in Scan, line 27:

form = Scan() # Otherwise, set the form to unbound
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I tried researching, but couldn't find the answer. (Django newbie here) . Thank you all!

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Scanner.forms import SubmitDomain

def Scan(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = SubmitDomain(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
        form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
        try:
            ## check if Tld Table has submitted domain already
            from Scanner.models import Tld
            Tld.objects.get(domainNm=form.cleaned_data['domainNm'])

        except Tld.DoesNotExist:
            print "Would you like to create an account?"
            ## redirect to account creation

        else:
            print "Do you have an account? Please login."
            ## redirect to account login

    else:
        form = Scan() # Otherwise, set the form to unbound
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from Scanner.models import Tld

class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Tld #Create form based off Model for Tld
        fields = ['domainNm',]

    def clean_domainName(self):
        val = self.clean_domainName('domainNm')
        return val

## This creates the form.
form = SubmitDomain()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from Scanner.models import Tld

class SubmitDomainForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tld
        fields = ['domainNm']

    def clean_domainName(self):
        val = self.cleaned_data.get('domainNm')
        if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=val).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Sorry that domain already
                exists, etc, etc')
        return val
```

In your view, do:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Scanner.forms import SubmitDomainForm

def scan(request):  # functions should start with a lowercase letter
    # Bind the post data to the form, if it exists.
    # No need for a separate if statement here
    form = SubmitDomainForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # save your model form, or do something else

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'form': form})
```

Hope that helps you out. Your view is currently instantiating the wrong type of object for the form, hence the TypeError. Your current clean method on your model form will never validate anything. It just sets the value equal to the clean function. Instead of cluttering your view with form validation logic, put that into the clean method of the form for that field and you can raise exceptions for different conditions.

Comment: So, the try{} and except{} block should go in the form itself instead?

Comment: Yes. Views are not where you want to be putting form validation logic :)

Comment: Haha, alright, as I said Im still really need to this whole MTV thing, but I've definitely learned a lot. So, is this considered server-side validation, since its validated off of the model's validation?  Is additional validation necessary as a best practice?

Comment: I always do validation on the server. If I'm submitting a form via ajax, I still get the validation errors back from the view as JSON instead of having a completely separate codebase for client-side validation. That just doubles your maintenance effort. You'd have to do server-side validation regardless, since JavaScript can be turned off.

Comment: If you're doing validation on the server, no further validation is necessary, in my opinion.

Comment: But, what Im saying is validation through a modelform - is that technically "server-side" ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Python code only gets evaluated on the server.

Comment: Excellent, gotta tip my hat to you for your help! Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. Django is a great framework, and particularly powerful around forms. If you haven't already, you might run through the tutorial on http://djangobook.com/. The "Practical Django Projects" book was also a huge help to me starting out.

Answer (score 0):

it fails when reuqest.method != "POST", in which case form is not defined

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not specific to django, it's basic python.  Your indentation is wrong.  The code should probably look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): # indent fixed here
        form.cleaned_data['domainNm']
```

Comment: holy moly, wow. i gotta get used to this indentation thing :) . Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is, I made this, but then got another type error. Please see the updated problem please

Comment: Also, the line of code that reads form.cleaned_data['domainNm'] does not do what you think it does.  Specifically it does not clean the form's 'domainNm' data.  It simply accesses the cleaned value (assuming that clean() has been called on the form) and then you are throwing the value away.

Comment: @CodeTalk I'm not sure what you mean by "set the form to unbound" but typically when the form is not valid, you would simply re-render the web page with the form validation errors displayed to the user.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/